# Ошибка The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

Tags: c++, windows

Ребят сможете помочь пожалуйста:
Создал программу на windows 10.  Пробую запускать ее на windows 7, а мне пишет "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher." Что мне нужно делать, чтоб запустить программу на windows 7. На windows 8, windows 10 все работает. Программа написана на c++.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Например, программа 64-разрядная, а запускается в 32-разрядной системе. Или использует что-то очень специфичное из WinAPI, так что в ее требованиях к системе прописана минимальная версия 8. Или просто при создании в настройках указана такая минимальная версия.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо проверить версию Windows SDK с которой собрано приложение, возможно версия слишком свежая для запуска на Win7.

Ещё стоит проверить разрядность собранного приложения, если собрана программа под **x64**, а запуск идёт на Win7 **x32** - приложение необходимо будет пересобрать под разрядность **x32**.